# Better way of logging after using proguard in android?

Tags: android, logging, proguard

After using progaurd, all the codes will be obfuscated. It would be difficult to analyze the log messages (like caught and uncaught exception stacktraces) and help me to fix the bugs. What is the better way of logging after using proguard in android? And is there a source map tool to covert the obfuscated to original one?

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard comes with ReTrace, a deobfuscation tool for stack traces.

See the Android documentation > Tools > ProGuard > [Decoding Obfuscated Stack Traces](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding).

See the ProGuard manual > [ReTrace](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/retrace/introduction.html).

Comment: What is the **stacktrace_file**? What kind of format is it? Is it possible to use a custom format file?